# How to allow Regex expression with Spaces

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

```
var validate = /^[@#&%][a-zA-Z0-9]{4}$/;
```

I need to allow the spaces as well in this Regex.

Comment: I noticed a lot of the solutions are not working for you--you might want to provide some info on exactly what you wish to match, as well as an example string to match against--and perhaps, even the string that is not matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this:

```
var validate = /^[@#&%][a-zA-Z0-9 ]{4}$/;
```

Note, just add a space within the brackets.

Comment: @user937194 cannot be. Your regex will fail matching for another reason then. Just execute `"#w 5e".match(/^[@#&%][a-zA-Z0-9 ]{4}$/);` in the browser console.

Answer (score 2):

It's exactly as easy as one might think: add a space to the regex where you want to match a space. Spaces work just like any other character in regex.

If you want to match any whitespace character (including tabs, etc.) you can use `\s` to match any whitespace character.

Answer (score 1):

if you want just regular space to be allowed then use a normal space in your brackets like this

```
/^[@#&%][a-zA-Z0-9 ]{4}$/
```

else if you wish to allow all white spaces such as tab or new line use `\s`:

```
/^[@#&%][a-zA-Z0-9\s]{4}$/
```

Comment: Not true: the space " " means space. `\s` includes *all whitespace characters*, including tabs, newlines, etc.

Comment: I'd like to mention that `/^[@#&%][a-zA-Z0-9_ -]{4}$/` will also match `_` (underscores) and `-` (hyphens) (edit: looks like Christoph edited the answer to change that)